# Drupal TB Megamenu: error after putting search-form into sub-menu

Tags: search, drupal, block, megamenu

I put the block for the search form into my sub-menu and now I am getting this error message any time at all my sides:

> Notice: Undefined index: subject in
>   template_preprocess_tb_megamenu_block() (Zeile 323 von
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal7\Sitename\sites\all\modules\tb_megamenu\tb_megamenu.themes.inc).

What can I do to solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

go to structure, blocks, locate the region where the TB Mega Menu: Main menu is and click on configure. Set Block title to `\"<none>\"`.

This worked for me. Good Luck!